# How to resolve a Promise within a loop function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

I am trying to to make several requests that are asynchronous, then push the data obtained into an array by using for loop. However, I encountered a problem that forloop itself doesnt return value which is required to resolve promise.. Also, I would like to use the array for rendering for GET method. 
So How do I complete promise within for loop and make sure that the array is filled before I render it for GET method. Sorry for my bad English. I am still new to the asynchronous concept, please teach me in easy words if possible. Also, if there are any better ways to solve the problem I would like to know.

```js
const currencyName = ["btc", "eth", "xrp"];
let dataCollections = [];
for (i = 0; i < currencyName.length; i ++) {
  dataCollections.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request.get(`https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/${currencyName[i]}jpy`, function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } if (dataCollections.length === 3) {
        dataColletions = [];
      }  else {
        resolve(JSON.parse(body));
      }
    });
  }));
}

//Promise.all(??).then(??)

//For rendering dataCollections
  app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("home", {dataCollections: dataCollections});
}
```

Comment: `map` over the `currencyName` array and produce an array of promises. Then use `Promise.all` to manage the responses. That way you don't need a loop.

Comment: Drop that weird `if (dataCollections.length === 3) {
        dataColletions = [];
      }` part and then instead just do `Promise.all(dataCollections).then(jsonBodies => { … })`

Comment: Do you want to fetch the data only once at application startup, or on each request?

Comment: It sounds like the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of explaining what you're trying to do, try to focus on explaining what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your advises guys. I am trying to fetch data everytime I reload a page. But I solved it by putting all the codes into GET method. Yes I think I had XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

1) consider naming your array `currencyNames` plural so that you can name your iterator `currencyName`.

2) Your for loop is reinventing the `array.map` function. Consider using `array.map` instead.

3) Your for loop has an impossible if clause (`if (dataCollections.length === 3)`) which also means the else clause is on the wrong if statement. I assume this is a typo.

Now to the core of your question, yes `Proimse.all(Array<Promise>)` is what you want; it resolves when all elements in its param resolve.

```
const currencyNames = ["btc", "eth", "xrp"];

let dataCollections = currencyNames.map(currencyName => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    request.get(`https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/${currencyName}jpy`, (error, response, body) => {
      if (error)
        reject(error);
      else
        resolve(JSON.parse(body));
    })));

//For rendering dataCollections
app.get("/", async (req, res) =>
    res.render("home", {dataCollections: await Promise.all(dataCollections)}));
```

Comment: It works like a charm!! Thank you for the help. I appreciate it alot. God bless you

Answer (score 0):

Make the endpoint async:

```
 app.get("/", async function(req, res) {
   res.render("home", {dataCollections: await Promise.all(dataCollections) });
 });
```